# Identify if a logstash pipeline is complete

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have below 2 queries

1. Is there a specific key in logstash API response which can identify that a pipeline (incremental) completed successfully? I checked [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.x/node-stats-api.html) where the Pipeline stats give an event response `...in, filtered, out...` but did not find anything which can clearly say that a pipeline completed successfully.
2. In logstash logs for a particular run I get below result, what does `(seconds)` denote here?

`[2018-07-14T01:00:05,117][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (4.753178s) SELECT a.*,....`
`[2018-07-14T02:00:45,221][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (42.543719s) SELECT pkey_ AS job_id,.....`